# Переменная не инкременируется по нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот мой код:

```
$(document).on('click', '.round', function() {
    var score = 0;
    score++;
    $('#result').html(score);
        this.remove();
});
```

Нужно, чтобы при клике `score` увеличивался на 1 и записывался в `$('#result')`.

Но почему-то он только пишет 1 и дальше не работает.

Comment: А `score` разве не уничтожается при выходе из замыкания, будучи локальной переменной? Из-за этого она заново создаётся и инициализируется при каждом вызове обработчика.

Comment: Я проверил без `this.remove();` тоже самое

Comment: @Arhad, тут нет замыкания

Comment: @Grundy, прошу прощения, перепутал понятия просто анонимной функции и замыкания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.round', function() {
    var score = 0;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    score++;
    $('#result').html(score);
        this.remove();
});
```

По вашему коду видно что при нажатии на кнопку переменной `score` присваивается снова 0;

Попробуйте инициализировать выше вашей функции, или сделать ее глобальной, после чего итерировать по нажатии на него

```
var score = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.round', function() {
    score++;
    $('#result').html(score);
        this.remove();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло!